# while loop terminating before it is supposed to C

Tags: c

This program is supposed to copy an existing txt file to a new txt code file. However is isn't working right. For some reason it always stops after the third iteration. 
  Suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char fileNameIn[100];
    char fileNameOut[100];
    FILE *ptrIn = NULL; //____ File Pointers
    FILE *ptrOut = NULL;
    char str[1000]; //this is used at fgets and it obtains sentences
    /*_________________Counter variables)*/
    char *token;
    int ctr = 0;
    int ndel = -1;
    char wordA[10];
    char sentence[101];

    char del[10] = " !-,.";
    ;
    int temp = 0;
    printf("Enter the input filename: \n");
    //  gets(fileNameIn);
    scanf("%s", fileNameIn);
    //printf("You entered: %s\n",fileNameIn);
    printf("Enter the output filename: \n");
    scanf("%s", fileNameOut);

    ptrIn = fopen(fileNameIn, "r"); // r is to read
    ptrOut = fopen(fileNameOut, "w"); //w is to write on file
    if (ptrIn == NULL || ptrOut == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //while(fgets (str,sizeof(str), ptrIn) )
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), ptrIn)) { // while we are not at the end of the file
        puts(str);
//      if(temp==0)
//      {
        token = strtok(str, del);
        temp = -1;

        printf(
                "Enter position of word to delete (Start counting at 0). Enter -1 to skip deletion:\n");
        scanf("%d", &ndel);
        printf("You selected: %d\n", ndel);

        while (token != NULL)   // while loop inside a sentence
        {
            if (ctr != ndel) {
                strcpy(wordA, token);

            }
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
            if (ctr != ndel) {
                strcat(sentence, wordA);
                strcat(sentence, " ");
                printf("halfway?");
            }
            ctr++;
        }   // endof sentence loop
        fprintf(ptrOut, "%s", sentence);
        printf("the sentence is now:\n%s", sentence);
        printf("___________________________________________");
        printf("\n");
        strcpy(sentence, "");
        ctr = 0;
        ndel = -1;
    }   //end of while loop eof

    printf("Finish the main: ");
    fflush(ptrOut);
    fclose(ptrIn);
    fclose(ptrOut);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is an example of the existing file:

test.txt:

```
hello my name is john.
this is a test.
after the third line the while
loop stops
this does the get copied
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe, and, while I see many errors in your code, I do not see anything that would cause that problem, either.

Comment: I know what would cause the problem -> **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**. And the evidence is that it works for @zwol, you `strcpy()` to a very small array so I guess that can be it, does the problem continue to happen if you redeclare `wordA` as `char wrodA[200]`?

Comment: Look at your code now, easier to read... isn't it?

Comment: What happens when you build a sentence that won't fit in `char sentence[101];`? There is no `strlen()` anywhere in the program.

Comment: It works very fine with me.

Comment: @TeeKea read my comment please, it's not impossible that in undefined behavior the **behavior** is the expected behavior, it's undefined after all.

Comment: the variable 'temp' is set but not used.  The compile operation should be set to enable all warnings, then those warnings need to be fixed

Comment: the returned value from scanf(and family) needs to be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  The max length of the file names needs to be limited so a buffer overrun (and resulting undefined behaviour and possible seg fault event) does not occur

Comment: the returned value from each of the calls to fopen need to be checked individually and if the second one fails, then the first file should be closed via fclose() before exiting

Comment: a few minutes with a debugger would have exposed the problem(s) with the code.  suggest using a debugger before posting a question.   We can debug most programs, but such simple bugs (and the code does not cleanly compile) should have been caught/fixed first.  I/we do expect the OP to make some minimal effort before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `strcat()` to `senetence` wihtout initializing it, `strcat()` will search for the terminating `nul` byte of it's first argument and start copying characters from it's second argument start from that position, so a simple

```
sentence[0] = '\0';
```

right after the outer `while` loop will fix it, but your code needs reformatting and you should make it safer by checking every single potential undefined behavior cause.

This is the code and it now works correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char fileNameIn[100]  = {0};
    char fileNameOut[100] = {0};
    FILE *ptrIn           = NULL;
    FILE *ptrOut          = NULL;
    char str[1024]        = {0};
    char *token           = NULL;
    int   ctr             = 0;
    int   ndel            = -1;
    char  wordA[1024]     = {0};
    char  sentence[1024]  = {0};
    char  del[]           = " !-,.";

    int temp = 0;
    printf("Enter the input filename  > ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%99s", fileNameIn);

    printf("Enter the output filename > ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%99s", fileNameOut);

    ptrIn = fopen(fileNameIn, "r"); // r is to read
    if (ptrIn == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file %s\n", fileNameIn);
        return -1;
    }

    ptrOut = fopen(fileNameOut, "w"); // w is to write on file
    if (ptrOut == NULL)
    {
        fclose(ptrIn);
        printf("Unable to open file %s\n", fileNameOut);
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), ptrIn)) // while we are not at the end of the file
    {
        puts(str);

        token = strtok(str, del);
        temp  = -1;

        printf("Enter position of word to delete (Start counting at 0) `-1 to skip deletion' > ");
        if (scanf("%d", &ndel) != 1)
            continue;
        printf("You selected: %d\n", ndel);

        sentence[0] = '\0';
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (ctr != ndel)
                strcpy(wordA, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
            if (ctr != ndel)
            {
                strcat(sentence, wordA);
                strcat(sentence, " ");
            }
            ctr++;
        }
        fprintf(ptrOut, "%s", sentence);

        printf("the sentence is now:\n%s", sentence);
        printf("\n");

        ctr  = 0;
        ndel = -1;
    }
    printf("Finish the main: ");

    fflush(ptrOut);
    fclose(ptrIn);
    fclose(ptrOut);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest he do this inside the loop just after the `fgets()` and eliminate the `strcpy(sentence, "")` from the bottom of his loop.

Comment: @jschultz410 I didn't check the full code, but this is the most obvious reason for problems so that's why I added this answer. You are surely right.

Comment: actually that change should be right AFTER the outer 'while' loop statement.

Comment: unfortunately adding: sentence[0]='\n\; will not fix the problem. The while loop only runs three times then it quits

Comment: @user4557512 Now I am still very busy even though I have been working since 5am and it's 7pm already, but when I feel that I don't want to work on my project anymore for today, I'll take a look.

Comment: @user4557512 I just checked your code and it works correctly after a few fixes. I will post the fixed code.

Comment: It definatly now works. Thank you very much for spending your time in this.